# How to get array values without forloop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a json_decode array which I can access the values fine with a `foreach` like this :

```
foreach ($prodvariants["result"]["sync_variants"] as $variant) {
                echo  $product_name = $variant['product']['name'];
            }
```

This works great.

But what if I do not want a `foreach`? How can I access the same values but without the forloop?

I tried this

```
$variant =$prodvariants["result"]["sync_variants"];
echo $product_name = $variant['product']['name'];
```

But when I try it like this,without the `foreach` I get error

> Notice: Undefined index: product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed one key there.

```
echo $product_name = $variant[0]['product']['name'];
                             ^^^
```

If `JSON` has numeric keys, it will be `[0]`. If you're using another keys, just change it.

But without any loop (for, foreach, while) you can't access to all variants in one line of code. You can choose just a single record. It's a non-sense to get loop out.